# Ubuntu Auto Software Installation Script

Tags: 16.04

I have 100 PCs where I need to install the following softwares:

```
Install 
- Net Beans
- Chromium
- Flash
- MySQL Workbench
- Colagit UI

sudo apt-get install tasksel

sudo tasksel install lamp-server

sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin

sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl

sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
<Directory /var/www>
------
Allow Override All
--
</Directory>

sudo apt-get install git-core
```

Is there a way to automate all of the above? For phpmyadmin and lamp-server, I need to intervene manually and add mysql root password. Can that be automated too?

Comment: Anyway the Allow Overwrite All block should probably go to /etc/apache2/apache.conf afaik. And after editing it and adding phpmyadmin don't forget to `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: If you have 100 computers, I suggest you start reading up on Ansible and start to use that instead, since it's easier and more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

#### automated apt install

You can use -y Option like

```
sudo apt install -y <package>
```

to automatically answer with Yes

#### Writing the file

The file edit you could do by

```
sudo echo 'a line' > <file>
```

For begin a new file and

```
sudo echo 'another line' >> <file>
```

To append lines to that file

#### Unattended mySQL installation

For the password prompt while mySQL installation refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7740571/7111561)

#### Unattended phpmyadmin installation

For the prompts for phpmyadmin installation refer to [this side](http://gercogandia.blogspot.de/2012/11/automatic-unattended-install-of.html) I didn't test it but it might still work.

**Note: Don't forget to restart apache2 after installing phpmyadmin**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: How about editing file and placing a block of content? And installing phpmyadmin with prompts?

Comment: edited my answers

Comment: The file content needs to be added in between and not at the end.

Comment: That's what I said. You have to write the complete file again with the echo .. so also the original lines. That's probably not the most elegant solution but it works ^^